# Removing the timestamp from a datetime in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

**Scenario:** I have a dataframe with multiple columns retrieved from excel worksheets. Some of these columns are dates where some values are dates (yyyy:mm:dd) and some are datetimes (yyyy:mm:dd 00.00.000000).

**Question:** How can I remove the time stamp from the dates when they are not the index of my dataframe?

**What I already tried:** From other posts here in SO ([working with dates in pandas - remove unseen characters in datetime and convert to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25653220/working-with-dates-in-pandas-remove-unseen-characters-in-datetime-and-convert) and [How to strip a pandas datetime of date, hours and seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41954938/how-to-strip-a-pandas-datetime-of-date-hours-and-seconds)) I found:

```py
pd.DatetimeIndex(dfST['timestamp']).date
```

and

```py
strfitme (df['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

But I can't seem to find a way to use those directly on the wanted column when it is not the index of my dataframe.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
dfST['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(dfST['timestamp'])
```

`to_datetime()` will infer the formatting of the date column. You can also pass `errors='coerce'` if the column contains non-date values.

After completing the above, you'll be able to create a new column containing only date values:

```
dfST['new_date_column'] = dfST['timestamp'].dt.date
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`dt.normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) to convert times to midnight (null times don't render) or [`dt.floor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) to floor the frequency to daily:

```py
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].dt.normalize()

df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].dt.floor('D')
```

Note that this keeps the dtype of the column `datetime64[ns]` because each element is still of type `pd.Timestamp`, whereas `dt.date` suggested in [Andrew L's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45860443/19123103) converts it to `object` because each element becomes type `datetime.date`.

[image: res]

Also, it's worth noting that `dt.normalize` and `dt.floor('D')` are both significantly faster (approx. 10 times faster for longer dataframes) than `dt.date`:

[image: perfplot]

Code used to produce the timings plot:

```py
from perfplot import plot
plot(
    setup=lambda n: pd.Series([pd.Timestamp('now')]*n),
    kernels=[lambda s: s.dt.date, lambda s: s.dt.normalize(), lambda s: s.dt.floor('D')],
    labels= ["col.dt.date", "col.dt.normalize()", "col.dt.floor('D')"],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(21)],
    xlabel='Length of column',
    title='Removing Time From Datetime',
    equality_check=lambda x,y: all(x.eq(y)));
```

Comment: This does not remove the timestamp.

Comment: @Murilo Are you talking about dtype because it does convert the times to midnight, so time won't be rendered (like in the image in the post).

Comment: You are correct! I didn't realized it wasn't going to render the midnight `00:00:00`. Why does that happens?