# Remove Minutes and Hours from Series

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Good Morning,

I have the following Dataframe (Year, Month, Day, Hour, Sec):

```
print(df)

     Date               Price
2018-01-02 09:42:00       2
2018-01-02 09:46:00       4
2018-01-02 10:22:00       6
...
```

I would like to get, without minutes and seconds:

```
print(final_df)

     Date               Price
2018-01-02                2
2018-01-02                4
2018-01-02                6
...
```

I tried:

```
df['Date'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(df['Date'], '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

But it reports *"strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series"*

Comment: refer to this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45860443/2545197

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If not datetime column need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
print (df.dtypes)
Date     object
Price     int64
dtype: object

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date

print (df.dtypes)
Date     object
Price     int64
dtype: object

print (df['Date'].head().apply(type))
0    <class 'datetime.date'>
1    <class 'datetime.date'>
2    <class 'datetime.date'>
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

Or if need datetimes without `hour`s, `minute`s and `second`s use [`dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.floor('d')

print (df.dtypes)
Date     datetime64[ns]
Price             int64
dtype: object

print (df['Date'].head().apply(type))
0    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...
1    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...
2    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

---

If datetime column:

```
print (df.dtypes)
Date     datetime64[ns]
Price             int64
dtype: object


df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.date

df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.floor('d')
```