# Python- how do I remove timestamp from datetime data throughout the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I found a similar thread but it dosent seem to work for me

[Removing the timestamp from a datetime in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45858155/removing-the-timestamp-from-a-datetime-in-pandas-dataframe)

say, My dataframe is of the following format:

[image: dataframe description]

**i tried doing this wile saving the csv but it didnt work:**

```
df3.to_csv('xy.csv',date_format = '%Y%m%d')
```

I also tried;

```
df3.datetime.strptime(df3, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

but it gives the

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'datetime'
```

I want to remove the timestamp throughout the dataframe, how do i go about doing this.thank you :)

Comment: Your dataframe code generates errors, please modify.

Comment: can you just show the head of your df, your code doesn't work

Comment: done with the edit, posted a snapshot though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with an example on my own with the help from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47752555/8660907

[image]

Comment: Otherwise, post more of your code for us to see the gist of what you have done and is now trying to achieve?