# Python- Drop hours:minutes:seconds form timedelta64[ns] data throughout the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe of following format:

[image: dataframe format]

the last column of my dataframe is 
[image: last column]

the hours, minutes and seconds data is completely irrelevant for my analysis work and i need to remove them.
I found the following resources in stack-overflow but none of them seem to help.

[Removing the timestamp from a datetime in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45858155/removing-the-timestamp-from-a-datetime-in-pandas-dataframe)

I tried

```
pd.DatetimeIndex(df3).dt.date
```

but the error occurs `Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)`

I tried dropping the H:M:S from only one column ['STDEV']

```
df3['STDEV']=df3['STDEV'].strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

but i get the error `'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'`

I also tried using `apply()`

```
df3.apply(pd.to_datetime(df3)).dt.date
```

which didnt work as well

Please let me know where i went wrong.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you get [timedeltas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html), not datetimes. So you can extract days for each column by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) with [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({
        'TCTN':('101','102','103'),
         '0':"855 days,626 days,866 days".split(','),
         '1':"946 days,485 days,182 days".split(','),
         '2':"1242 days,1985 days,0 days".split(','),
         '3':"345 days,1864 days,361 days".split(',')
}).set_index('TCTN')
df3 = df3.iloc[:, 1:].apply(pd.to_timedelta)
print (df3)
            1         2         3
TCTN                             
101  946 days 1242 days  345 days
102  485 days 1985 days 1864 days
103  182 days    0 days  361 days

df3 = df3.apply(lambda x: x.dt.days)
print (df3)
        1     2     3
TCTN                 
101   946  1242   345
102   485  1985  1864
103   182     0   361
```